# Appending to several tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Has anyone ever seen any sample SQL Server code to "generically" append records using multiple tables?

We have a weird process here where we use a set of about a dozen tables of "current" data and a matching set of tables with "previous" data (I know there are better ways to do this, but this is what I have to deal with).

I have to move records each week from the set of "current" tables to their "previous" counterpart tables, but I don't want to create a series of INSERT INTO statements separately for each table with all the fields hard-coded for each one.

Thanks!

Comment: Some kind of replication/synchronization?

Comment: Is [this script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2179622/87698) what you are looking for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I copy all fields of one table to another, wider table in SQL Server 2005 Express?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2179463/how-can-i-copy-all-fields-of-one-table-to-another-wider-table-in-sql-server-200)

Comment: Close; maybe something like:
  
INSERT INTO 
XXX.dbo.CurrentTableOne 
(Field1, Field2, Field3, AndSoOn) 
SELECT 
Field1, Field2, Field3, AndSoOn 
FROM 
XXX.dbo.PreviousTableOne
  
and then
  
INSERT INTO 
XXX.dbo.CurrentTableTwo 
(Field5, Field6, Field7, SomethingElse, AnotherField) 
SELECT  
Field5, Field6, Field7, SomethingElse, AnotherField 
FROM 
XXX.dbo.PreviousTableTwo
   
and so forth, where there are several pairs of tables like CurrentTableOne and PreviousTableOne, CurrentTableTwo and PreviousTableTwo, etc. I have all those tables in a "table of tables".

Comment: Check out MERGE()

Answer (score 1):

The following script will create the INSERT statements dynamically based on a "table of table names". Will that do? It doesn't take source database name or destination database into account though, but I'm sure you can adapt the script if you need it.

---

```
CREATE TABLE #table_of_tables(
    src_table_name SYSNAME NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    dest_table_name SYSNAME NOT NULL
);
--INSERT INTO #table_of_tables(src_table_name,dest_table_name)VALUES('src_table','dest_table');

DECLARE @copy_stmts NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT 
        ';INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(dest_table_name) + '('+cols+') SELECT ' + cols + ' FROM ' + QUOTENAME(src_table_name)
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT
                tot.src_table_name,
                tot.dest_table_name,
                cols=STUFF(
                    (SELECT ','+QUOTENAME(c.COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS c WHERE c.TABLE_NAME=t.TABLE_NAME FOR XML PATH('')),
                    1,
                    1,
                    ''
                )
            FROM
                #table_of_tables AS tot
                INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t ON
                    t.TABLE_NAME=tot.src_table_name AND
                    t.TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
        ) AS tbd
    FOR
        XML PATH('')
);

--SELECT @copy_stmts; --> select to verify statements
EXEC sp_executesql @copy_stmts; --> to launch the insert statements

DROP TABLE #table_of_tables;
```